# How to show in HTML a circle filled by one color within a cell table?

Tags: html, css

I need to show a circle filled by one color within a table cell.  Somehow, I found an example that works but does not work reliably. Please, see the code below.
On IE the circle becomes a vertically elongated oval.  The same can happen on Mozilla with bigger cell height.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>circle</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .circle_green { 
                width:1%;
                padding:10px 11px;
                margin:0 auto;
                border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
                border-radius:25px;
                background-color:green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="circle_green"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not work on all browsers, especially not with the older ones.  Some of them have problems with the  radius.

Comment: Maybe, but Mozilla also gives problems - something needs to be done with vertical alignment

Comment: Sachin gives you the correct answer, use a polyfiller for IE radius. set vertical alignment(middle or top) on td to fix ur error

Comment: Somebody down-voted this question - why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `border-radius:100%` instead of `border-radius: 25px;` in your css.

and remove the unused `<img />` tag from the markup.

You are using border-radius here so make sure your browser supports CSS3 Specifications.

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BpVLu/)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

CSS

```css
.filled-circle {
  padding: 2px 11px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #f38e23;
}
```

HTML

```html
<span class="filled-circle"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

You also could create a SVG (Scalable Vector Object) to do this.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <circle cx="41" cy="41" r="40" stroke="#333" stroke-width="1" fill="#800000"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use same width, height and border-radius. Example:

```
        width:25px;
        height:25px;
        border-radius:25px;
```